# Why does Debug mode not guarantee the completion of a Task (.net core, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, task

every one.

I am a newbie to here and the programming world.

MS docs is saying A task is a single work that is guaranteed to complete.
I found it is true in release build but not in debug build.

My testing code is very simple.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine("1st Code executed");
            Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2nd Code executed");
                Console.WriteLine("3rd Code executed");
            });
            task.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("4th Code executed");

            Console.ReadLine();
           }
```

In debug mode, it results in one of three below:

```
         /*Mostly
         * 1st Code executed
         * 4th Code executed

         * rarely
         * 1st Code executed
         * 4th Code executed
         * 2nd Code executed

         * rarely
         * 1st Code executed
         * 4th Code executed
         * 2nd Code executed
         * 3rd Code executed */
```

In release build, there is no exception that all four lines are shown before the app finishes, although lines in the task and 4th line comes in arbitrary order.

My question is what makes the app finish without completion of a task in debug mode and, in addition, how I can fix it thru debug options, if any.

Comment: A task is not guaranteed to finish unless you `await` it or call `Wait` or `Result` or do something else to wait for it.

Comment: Thanks, John. I was seeing when a task completes without await-like calls. I put the ReadLine() at the end of Main to block it to finish.  I expected the task would finish within reasonable period of time by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick answer

Your `Main` method and your task run in parallel, and the Main method does not wait the task to finish.

In release mode, the task is "lucky". It finishes before Main. Not in debug mode. In both case the execution is random.

The fact they run in parallel explain why your can't predict the order of the printed lines.

## Explanations

A `Task` is a thread that comes from the thread pool, so they are **background threads**.

The process running your code (which consist of all your threads) does not wait for background threads to finish in order to terminate. The process only wait that **foreground threads** have finished.

Then you may want to use the `Thread` class because they are foreground by default. But using Task is easier. So @John Wu's comment is totally relevant:

> A task is not guaranteed to finish unless you await it or call Wait or
>   Result or do something else to wait for it

You simply want to add at the end of your code:

```
task.Wait();
```

However you'll never be able to predict the order of the printed lines, because the threads run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. Actually, I intentionally put the Console.ReadLine(), instead of calling Wait(), at the last of the main method hoping to give chance or time for other tasks to complete before I hit Enter to finish Main, the foreground thread. I thought other tasks had to finish because the main was not finished although it was blocked by ReadLine(). Release build approved it without exception but Debug build didn't. If blocked main stops other background tasks to complete, can we call it as parallel programming?

Comment: @BigSquare If one of your thread is listening for an input with `Console.ReadLine` and another thread outputs to the console with `Console.WriteLine`, then it must be parallel execution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)
Upvote or mark my answer as accepted if it has helped you in understanding tasks ;-)

Comment: it surely helped me and marked it. However, feeling floating. from yesterday, Debug mode also began to show 4 lines all the time.

Comment: @BigSquare Then re read the answer until you make sure to understand why ;-) Feel free to continue asking questions here